# Why do we have [xamarin] and not [microsoft] or [apple]?

Tags: discussion, tags

I remember a while ago [microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) got burned for good. Why do we have [xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xamarin)?

Comment: Well, it is probably meant to refer to the Xamarin platform, not the Xamarin company.

Comment: I wonder if apple should be burninated again at the same time? There's 212 pages of questions tagged with it now

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi The first couple of paragraphs of the xamarin tag wiki are about the company, the rest is about the platform. Maybe we just need to edit the first two paragraphs out of the wiki?

Comment: @JonK, maybe. It's not like a description of the company is on-topic related to the technology itself. I don't think we would miss these two paragraphs very much.

Comment: We also have [tag:ibm] and [tag:intel]

Comment: Well, Xamarin is owned by Microsoft now so it can't be about the company :)  People dislike tags like [apple] and [microsoft] primarily because they are assumed to attract questions from end-users.  Not that banning them helps it all, they just move to other tags like [osx] and [windows].  And I can't filter them out anymore :(

Comment: If the tag is really meant for the Xamarin platform then probably the description of the tag should not be about the history of the company.

Comment: The "Apple" tag wasn't burned and recreated. Questions have had the tag continuously since at least 2009. It's been proposed and maybe worked on, but never finished.

Comment: What if we renamed the tag to xamarin-platform?

Comment: @Teepeemm, why? To differentiate from the company? SO is not about companies in the first place :)

Answer (score 25):

I will assume that Frédéric Hamidi is correct and the tag is about the platform.

In this case, we desperately need to edit the information about the company out of the tag excerpt. It's irrelevant at best and  harmful at worst.

As a person unfamiliar with the technology, I wouldn't have guessed that it was also the name of a platform. In fact, I have only a vague idea what everyone means by "platform" after reading the entire wiki.

As someone who frequently relies on tag excerpts when editing, I think my view on what should be included in the tag excerpt is valuable.

I suggest that we change the excerpt to something along the lines of:

> For questions about using the Xamarin IDE, its form builder, the Xamarin Visual Studio plugin, or a Xamarin API.

Again, I'm unfamiliar with the technology, so feel free to correct me. (I only have a rough idea what it's about from the tag wiki ... it's an IDE, right?)

I also think it would be valuable to include related tags, including ones that should be used instead of [xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xamarin). We should also specify that questions about Xamarin the company are off-topic for SO, if it's ever a problem in this tag.

Comment: As I understand it, the platform is not only the IDE (Xamarin Studio) but also the glue layers between Mono and the native platforms (`Xamarin.iOS` and `Xamarin.Android`).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yes, after doing a little more research I'm starting to see what you mean. I'm trying to think of better wording; *questions about Xamarin the glue* isn't ideal. :) What about referring to it as [Xamarin APIs](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/)?

Comment: Seems nice enough to me :)

Comment: Relevant not-xkcd yet: [people don't read tag excerpts/wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256114/)

Comment: @Braiam It's the power users that read them ;)

Comment: As an aside, a platform is, basically speaking, what you want to put your code on.  More specifically, it can be the target hardware (such as x86 systems, x64 systems, RISC systems, smartphones, a specific gaming console, etc.), the target OS (such as Windows, *nix, Mac OS, etc.), or even specific software that you want it to run on (such as .NET Framework, or... can't think of any others off the top of my head).  That's what the term is generally used as, to my knowledge.

Comment: As a C# dev, I would assume that a [tag:xamarin] question was about the Xamarin libraries/platform/api, not the company.